# What does "all-in" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm translating an [article](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018) which is about wearable products (smart watches). I don't know what does **all-in** mean in the following context:

> If 2014 was the dawn of wearables in the sense that it represents the
>   largest inroads made for a new product category, then I hope 2015 will
>   be the year that really prompts me to really go **all-in** with the
>   technology.

I searched about *all-in*, but I think *all-in* in above context is different.

Comment: It would be nice if you included what you learned about _all-in_ when you searched for it. That way, we know what you already know.

Comment: **All-in** means the same as **all-out**. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**to go all-in** is originally a poker term: 
When a player puts all his chips on stake. Either he wins or he's out.

So, if one uses the term "go all in" it's either all or nothing.

- In a business context, one ventures all resources and either succeeds or fails.
- In other senses, it may mean having no backup plan or doing something full-time.

Here, the author wants to use the new smart watch exclusively in 2015.

Comment: These days, you may also find it in MMORPGs like World of Warcraft! To tell everyone to start doing damage to the targeted monster, with all their best damage abilities, the raid leader says: "All-in!"

Answer (score 1):

'All-in' means 'totally or 100%'. With anything new, particularly technology, many people start slowly or cautiously for any number of reasons, then suddenly gain interest. Other people, of course, go all-in from the start.